# Fixed effect OLS with normalized coefficients in R

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect, heterogeneity

I want to estimate the following fixed effects regression:
$$
Y_i = \gamma_{m}+ \lambda_b + \delta_{gb}D_{igb}+\varepsilon_i,
$$
where $\gamma_m$ is municipality fixed effect, $\lambda_b$ is birth cohort fixed effect and $D_{igb}$ is indicator, whether the individual belongs to birth cohort $b$ and treatment group $g$, where the treatment groups $g$ are collections of municipalities; i.e. each municipality belongs to one treatment group.

I believe this requires several normalizations to avoid multicollinearity; I would like to set $\lambda_1=0$ and $\delta_{g1}=1$ for all $g$; I believe that should be enough. Is there a simple way to specify this in R?

lm() does run, but it's not quite clear, how does it do the normalizations (some of the coefficients are NA etc.).

Comment: Welcome to CV. Please post your summary output. It will improve your chances of getting a response. It will also be easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I actually solved the problem I was having. I didn't realize, I need to use : instead of * for interactions. Or, well... It didn't get exactly, what I asked, but the default in lm() is close enough.

Comment: I’m glad you got to the bottom of it on your own. The `:` operator is helpful if you want to drop some of your constituent terms. However, I often recommend `*` in practice because it might alert you to a collinearity problem you didn’t know existed.